# Sending emails in bulk and catching unsuccessful attempts

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

The frontend code contains a list of names with checkboxes next to each name. The goal is to have an email sent to all the names that are checked. When the submit button is clicked, an array of ID's  (for each user) is sent to my backend.

The backend code queries the DB (mongo using the mongoose odm) and finds the users. I have a few tasks I need to complete on the backend:

- Find the users with the provided array of IDs
- Create and send an email to each user
- If the email is successful, update a document field in the DB that the email was sent
- If the email failed, send the user's name back to the frontend to notify the "sender" that the email attempt was unsuccessful.

I've been working on this code for longer than I'd like to admit... Here is what I have at the moment (I am concerned about the backend code):

```js
exports.sendEmailToUsers = function (req, res, next) {
  mongoose.model('SpendingReport').find({ _id: { $in: req.body.recipientIds } }).populate('report user')
    .find({ 'report.emailedReport': { $exists: false } })  // this needs to be refined for dev, new reports will have an emailedGradePost property
    .then(spendingReports => {
      return Bluebird.map(spendingReports, spendingReport => {
        const email = new Email({ email: spendingReport.user.email, name: spendingReport.user.fullName }, {})

        return email.send()
          .then(() => {
            spendingReport.report.update({ emailedReport: new Date() })
            // I don't need anything returned if it is successful, this feels weird though, map doesn't
            // seem like the  correct function to use.

            // return {spendingReport.report.emailedGradePost}
          })
          .catch(e => {
            // I am catching each email's error so I know which email failed
            return { error: e, user: spendingReport.user.fullName }
          });
      });
    })
    .then(unsuccessfulAttempts => {
      // the array has the error obect from the .catch and also undefined values for the successful attempts
      console.log(unsuccessfulAttempts);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200); //  filler status for now
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

Here are my questions:

- I am using `Bluebird.map`, this feels like a code smell. In theory, I could just use `.map` on the `spendingReports` array which contains an array of documents from the DB and create an email with the info from each `spendingReport`. The problem is, I will lose access to the `spendingReport` object when I return the emails to the next `.then()` in the promise chain, e.g.

```js
exports.sendEmailToUsers = function (req, res, next) {
  mongoose.model('SpendingReport').find({ _id: { $in: req.body.recipientIds } }).populate('report user')
    .find({ 'report.emailedReport': { $exists: false } })  // this needs to be refined for dev, new reports will have an emailedGradePost property
    .then(spendingReports => {
      return spendingReports.map(spendingReport => new Email({ email: spendingReport.user.email, name: spendingReport.user.fullName }, {}));
      // {email: email, spendingReport: spendingReport} I might need this format instead, referenect the note
      // in the next promise chain.
    })
    .then(emails => {
      return Bluebird.map(emails, email => {
        email.send()
          .then(() => {
            // Note: I lost access to "spendingReport", I would need to pass this object
            // with each email object {email: email, spendingReport: spendingReport}
            spendingReport.report.update({ emailedReport: new Date() })
              .catch(e => {
                return { error: e, user: spendingReport.user.fullName };
              })
          })
      })
    })
    .then(unsuccessfulAttempts => {

      console.log(unsuccessfulAttempts);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200); //  filler status for now
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

- I have a nested promise chain (inside of `Bluebird.map`, the email is sent, then it is saved to the db that it was successful). I know nesting promises is an anti-pattern. The only way to alleviate the nested promise is to pass along the document objects associated with each email in each `.then`, this feels like more of a burden compared to just having the nested promise chain in `Bluebird.map`
- I don't know what to return in `Bluebird.map` when an email is successful and it successfully saves. Right now I don't return anything, so `undefined` is returned.
- Ideally, I could send all the emails in parallel, like `Promise.all([email.send(), email.send(), email.send()])`, however, it makes saving to the DB that the email was successful more challenging (I would need to get access again to the `spendingReports` documents again and update the `report`, this feels like a lot of querying).

Comment: You need to return the `spendingReport.report.update` promise or the `then()` it is inside will resolve immediately

Answer (score 3):

use async-await can reduce your problem (since you can get all item by index)

```
async function(req, res, next) {
  let spendingReports = await mongoose.model('SpendingReport').find(...)
  let emails = spendingReports.map(r=>new Email(...))
  let sendingmails = emails.map(e=>e.send())
  let success=[],fail=[];
  await Promise.all(sendingmails.map((s,i)=>s.then(_=>success.push(i)).cache(_=>fail.push(i))))

  //now you have index of success and failed mails. 
  //just process these data and do whatever you want
}
```

---

the intermediate data is not necessary, like this one-liner (don't really do this)

```
async function(req, res, next) {
  let success=[],fail=[];
  await Promise.all(await mongoose.model('SpendingReport').find(...).then(spendingReports => spendingReports.map(r=>(new Email(...)).send().then(_=>success.push(r)).cache(_=>fail.push(r))))

  //now you have success and failed spendingReports. 
  //just process these data and do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Ha, I was just going to suggest this in a comment. Good answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the node version the project is in doesn't support async await, I do like this solution though!